# Listview Item layout pushes the linearlayout off the screen

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and am trying to create a list view row item as follows:

- On the far left of the listview item I need two stacked text views
- In the center of the listview item I need an additional two stacked text view
- On the far right I need a checkbox

I want to make the width of the center textviews a constant size, irrespective to the length of text.

Every time I adjust the middle linear layout, it pushes the checkbox off the screen unless I manually give it a width (which will not work for multiple screen sizes). Can someone please help?

I've tried using weights and all but I can't figure it out.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/starttime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="10:35am"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#929692"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="11:55am"
        android:textColor="#929692"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sessionname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ok this is where my text goes it is very long 
        and it will push stuff off"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        android:textColor="#929692" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/middle"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:checked="false" />
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your Left layout is `wrap_content` and middle one is `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left"` . So this will push the layout out out screen . If you want to divide the layout horizontally  Simply use [constraintlayout Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html).

Comment: I've never used this, can you explain further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used constraintlayout and it worked!